# Relax- Did I use relax correctly?

Tags: word-usage

Did I use relax correctly?

It is just 5 mins walk to the sea where you can go to relax and drink a glass of wine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but I'd personally remove "go to";

It's 5 minutes to the sea where you can relax and enjoy/drink a glass of wine.

Or

It's just *a* 5 minute walk to the sea where you can relax and drink a glass of wine.

I definitely think enjoy is more idiomatic than drink in this context!

Also note singular minute when referring to the walk.